# Setting C3.JS X axis and text

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

Is it possible to set the X-axis ticks and text separate from the column data values with C3.JS charts?

I have data being loaded for a 24hr period but where the time stamps may be for any time in that period. I have been requested to provide X-axis tick labels for only every 90 minute interval.

Comment: So you want to set `axis-x-tick-values` separately from `axis-x-tick-labels`?

Comment: More accurately I would say I want to set the ticks and tick labels explicitly, separate from the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`axis-x-tick-values`](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-values) separately from data labels.

An example form the docs:

http://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_values.html

Comment: Why does that demo show 1/5 and 1/10 as the tick text?

Comment: @MattW That's the date it was set to in the code below. These labels can be different.

Comment: Oh yes. D'oh! Was expecting a different format of date.